# T invariant probability measure on a compact space $X$

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T:X\to X$ be a continuous map defined on the compact space $X$. I read that if $X$ is a metric space then the set of T-invariant probability measure is not empty.

I want to know if this result is true when $X$ is only a compact topological space (maybe Hausdorff if it's neccesary). I tried to construct a counterexample but I couldn't =(

The proof that I read uses some properties of metric space so I could not reply the metric case proof =(

Comment: I am sorry that I do not quite understand your question. You ask whether the result is true for a compact metric space, but in the paragraph it seems you already know this result for compact metric space.

Comment: EDITED: Typing error

Comment: Maybe this helps: if $X$ is compact, Hausdorff and second-countable, then it is metrizable.  What is your space of interest?